# LinearLayout doesn't work. Title does not show up?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a question for you all. When I have a simple text in an xml file in eclipse. Why doesn't the title show up?

I have searched for similar problems, but can't find it on stackoverflow. Hopefully someone can help me.

unfortunately, I can't post pictures. Well, the text: @string/ondergewicht is the title of the text.

@/string/ondergewichttekst is the text wich I've used.

And this is the code I've used. Sorry if this is a stupid question, and I'm sure it is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewichttekst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/ondergewichttekst" 
    android:textSize="16sp"/>      

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewicht"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/ondergewicht"
    android:textSize="30sp"
     />



</LinearLayout>
```

So, the ondergewichttekst is showed, but the overgewicht is not. Maybe is there something like an text order?

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewicht"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/ondergewicht"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewichttekst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/ondergewichttekst"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the order of the elements in the LinearLayout decides the order of its appearance on the screen. Happy programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ... It works fine for me.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical" >
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/ondergewichttekst"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>     android:textStyle="italic"
>     android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
>     android:gravity="center" 
>     android:text="@string/ondergewichttekst" 
>     android:textSize="16sp"/>      
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/ondergewicht"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>     android:textStyle="italic"
>     android:gravity="center" 
>     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
>     android:text="@string/ondergewicht"
>     android:textSize="30sp"
>      />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, the title was on the screen now. The other answer shows it further! Thank you for your efforts! Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You have horizontal orientation in your Linear Layout and your first TextView has `layout_width = match_parent` This doesn't make sense, there is no more room for the second TextView.
Use vertical orientation of layout or use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for widths and heights.

Answer (score 0):

You have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in both `TextView`s of a `horizontal` `LinearLayout` so the first `TextView` is taking up all of the `width`. Change them to `wrap_content`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewichttekst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/ondergewichttekst" 
    android:textSize="16sp"/>      

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ondergewicht"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="@string/ondergewicht"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

Comment: No, stil don't got it?

Comment: Can you see both in the graphical view of your IDE?

Comment: No, I can't see them both. Only the text.